# How can I get all frames of stack traces in "!htrace -diff" result?

Tags: memory-leaks, windbg, handle-leak

It seems that  "!htrace -diff" can only show 16 frames. How can I increase the frame counts in the stack traces? The following is one of the handles leaked detected by !htrace -diff. I can't read anything from it without a complete stack trace.

```
Handle = 0x00000f7c - OPEN
Thread ID = 0x00001cc4, Process ID = 0x00009f20

0x01b8dad8: +0x01b8dad8
0x018c6e93: +0x018c6e93
0x7788179a: +0x7788179a
0x000a20bb: +0x000a20bb
0x753ab069: +0x753ab069
0x7539cf87: +0x7539cf87
0x75322776: +0x75322776
0x7539d07e: +0x7539d07e
0x7539c549: +0x7539c549
0x778ae707: +0x778ae707
0x7785c32e: +0x7785c32e
0x77a2ff66: ntdll!ZwCreateEvent+0x00000012
0x69bffc58: verifier!AVrfpNtCreateEvent+0x0000006b
0x77390d93: KERNELBASE!CreateEventExW+0x0000006e
0x773911c6: KERNELBASE!CreateEventW+0x00000027
0x69bffd8f: verifier!AVrfpCreateEventW+0x00000078
```

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/8aa1a9de-7579-435e-b8f3-d6d28ab23579/is-there-a-way-to-control-callstack-depth-for-htrace) point to [this one](http://www.archivum.info/microsoft.public.windbg/2006-07/00046/Re-!htrace-Order-of-output-and-increasing-the-number-of-displayed-call-frames.html) Which tells that basically it is hard coded.

> The maximum depth of the stack trace is currently hardcoded to 16 
>   (although it's possible it will change in the future). Also, that
>   includes  a few entries for the kernel-mode portion of the stack
>   trace. Those stack  trace entries can be displayed by kernel or driver
>   developers by using  !htrace in a kernel debugger. So getting around
>   11 user-mode entries for  each of your traces sounds accurate.

Comment: thanks, I also had read that article. but any other ways to debug handle leak if htrace can't return a full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't.

Assuming that you have symbols set up correctly, I see the following possibility

> Some of the traces reported by !htrace may be from a different process context. In this case, the return addresses may not resolve properly in the current process context, or may resolve to the wrong symbols.

Source: WinDbg help (`.hh !htrace`)

This can happen if a different process injects handles into your process and the addresses correlate to that process. In this case, the process ID listed by `!htrace` does not match the process you're debugging (type `|` (pipe) to get the process ID).

In such a case, you can attach to the process (`.attach 0x<pid>`, `0n` is default here) and try to get the remaining callstack from there, but I never did this myself.

Comment: All my works are in one process. Are there any other ways to get the leaked handles without a full stack traces?

Comment: Such a process could be a virus scanner or other programs that are deep down in the system. Have you tried turning them off?